# How can I make a delegate to a mapView in Reference Outlets

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I'm starting with swift code and I'm not being able to make a delegate in a map view.

This is how I have:

[image]

And this is how it should be:

[image]

I know it must be a very simple thing but I'm having a hard time.

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it starting with a right click on the map view, and then dragging the delegate to the view controller which implements the delegate, in the following image it is the view controller that holds the map view.

[image]

Before setting the delegate it is necessary to set view controller class:

[image]

But I believe the easier way (and best) to set the delegate, if you have an outlet connection to a view controller, is by code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @claudio thanks, it was super easy but I was having a hard time to find how to do. Thanks it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it with the storyboard you could drag from MapView to the UIController and a delegate option should appear if the class has it inherited from the MapView.

Another way and one that makes the most sense to me is to create the MapView object inside the ViewController and instanciate it manually inside the onViewDidLoad() as MapView.delegate = self